# JS difference between types of global variables

Tags: javascript, oop, global-variables

According to this:

```
(function(window) {
    window.MyClass1 = function(val) {
        this.val = val;
        console.log(this.val);
    };
}(window));

(function() {
    window.MyClass2 = function(val) {
        this.val = val;
        console.log(this.val);
    };
}());

(function() {
    this.MyClass3 = function(val) {
        this.val = val;
        console.log(this.val);
    };
}());

(function() {
    MyClass4 = function(val) {
        this.val = val;
        console.log(this.val);
    };
}());

new MyClass1('works1');
new MyClass2('works2');
new MyClass3('works3');
new MyClass4('works4');
```

on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo0sckcq/)

What is the difference between MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3 and MyClass4? Aren't all of them attached to the window object in the exact same way?
What's the best practice and why?

Comment: MyClass3 and MyClass4 do not work in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: `MyClass3` will be attached to the `this` reference of the `function` called, which is not necesarily the global object (e.g inside a requirejs module etc..) So using `this` can be tricky

Comment: `MyClass4` might even throw an error no `var` declaration and no object to attach to.

Comment: to sum up the above 4 examples would be equivalent only under very specific cases, not for the rest

Comment: thx to you. so 3 and 4 is bad ;) but 1 and 2 any differences? Is 1 just the "well-behaved way"?

Comment: There is no practical difference between 1 and 2. Perhaps differently optimised script engines might lookup local variables faster than global. Or not. "Best practice" would be to use a function declaration and remove the pointless IIFE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3 and
>   MyClass4? Aren't all of them attached to the window object in the
>   exact same way?

There's no meaningful difference between `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`.

`MyClass3` will not work in strict mode because `this` inside the IIFE will be `undefined`, not equal to `window`.

`MyClass4` will not work in strict mode because strict mode disallows implicit globals (variables assigned to without declaration) such as `MyClass4`.

In non-strict mode, all four will work.  In my opinion, implicit globals are simply evil (way too prone to accidents) so `MyClass4` should be ruled out even in non-strict mode.  And, if `MyClass3` wants to assign to `window`, it seems it may as well just refer to `window.MyClass3` (like `MyClass2` does) rather than go through `this` which just makes the code less obvious and incompatible with strict mode.

> What's the best practice and why?

The best practice would be an implementation that works in both strict and non-strict mode and is as simple as possible to achieve the goal.  Since the IIFE is not adding any functionality that is being used, I don't see why it's needed in this circumstance.  Simplicity is somewhat governed by opinion, but I'd say nothing more than this is needed:

```
function MyClass1(val) {
    this.val = val;
    console.log(this.val);
};

var x = new MyClass1("foo");
console.log(x.val);            // "foo"
```